# How can I set a fixed row height and column width in Telerik WinForms RadScheduler?

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

How can I set a fixed row height and column width in Telerik (UI for WinForms) RadScheduler when using a timeline view with grouping by resources?

I could find only the *Resources per view* property which automatically changes the height when the resource numbers are different.

Comment: Refer this:https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/details/auto-expand-the-height-of-the-appointment-to-accomodate-the-entire-subject-in-month-view

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the timeline view, I'm afraid this is the only way to control the height, by actually setting the Resources per view as you mentioned.
This was confirmed by Stefan, one of Telerik's admins. Please, check his answer in this [post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/row-height-for-schedular).

As for the width, I'm still researching it, however, it can be changed in proportion to other columns which are considered to be 1 by default, so if you set one of columns' width to 2, it will be twice the standard size:

```
((SchedulerTimelineViewElement)radScheduler1.ViewElement).SetColumnWidth(0, 2); // 0 being the column index and 2 being the width
```

[Edit: This is also mentioned in the [documentation]](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/scheduler/views/timeline-view#modifying-the-size-of-the-columns)